# HTML5 video (mp4) not playing in iOS (nginx server)

Tags: ios, html, video, nginx, html5-video

I am developing a website that features videos.

I received reports that the videos are not playing on iOS, which I confirmed by using iOS Simulator.

After several tests I noticed that:
1- If I access this url http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4 using iOS Sim it plays fine.
2- If I upload the same video to my server (nginx) and access it directly it does not play.

I thought it was a MIME type issue but the Nginx mime.types has

```
    video/3gpp                              3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp4                               mp4;
    video/mpeg                              mpeg mpg mpe;
    video/ogg                               ogv;
    video/quicktime                         mov;
    video/webm                              webm;
    video/x-flv                             flv;
    video/x-mng                             mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                          asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                          wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                         avi;
```

Any suggestions? Is the iOS simulator (os x 10.9 latest xcode) reliable for these tests?

Comment: check the response headers in both the w3schools site and your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was an encoding issue after all.
Not sure why it didn't play the video I downloaded from w3c example, but I reencoded my mp4s using [youtube's h264 settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en) and now it works.

Comment: Did reencoding the example movie fix that one as well? Can you explain a bit more what you mean with youtube's h264 settings?

Comment: The answer is not clear. How did you fix the problem?

Comment: I re-encoded the video using youtube h264 settings (edited my answer and added link) that solved the issue.